# Can I automate the calculate process and direct update to the table using Laravel Framework?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm new in programming, and I'm currently working on a rubric assessment module with Laravel Framework.
This is my code to handle the calculation of the marks in the Controller. However, I would like to update the calculation in real time without refreshing the page. Due to I'm lacking of knowledge in Javascript and JQuery, I would like to ask is there any way or sample code to perform the process in real time?

```
 foreach ($rubricArtifactDetails as $rubricArtifactDetail) {
            foreach ($rubricCriteriaDetails as $rubricCriteriaDetail) {
                if ($rubricArtifactDetail['rubricArtifactId'] == $rubricCriteriaDetail['rubricArtifactId']) {
                    $finalMark = 0;
                    if ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] !== null && $rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator'] !== null) {
                        $finalMark = ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] + $rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator']) / 2;
                    } elseif ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] === 0 || $rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator'] === 0) {
                        $finalMark = ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] + $rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator']) / 2;
                    } elseif ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] === null && $rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator'] === null) {
                        $finalMark = 0;
                    } elseif ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] === null) {
                        $finalMark = $rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator'] / 2;
                    } elseif ($rubricCriteriaDetail['markModerator'] === null) {
                        $finalMark = $rubricCriteriaDetail['markSupervisor'] / 2;
                    }
                    $finalMarkArray[$t] = $finalMark;
                    $t++;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my sample output for the rubrics, however it only update the marks by clicking the submit button.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pg3F.jpg

Comment: You could use laravel-livewire for this

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this in realtime, you need to use AJAX.
jQuery's `$.ajax` is one of the simplest method to perform this task.

- Create an independent web route for calculation and link it to the respective controller's method.
- Create a `$.ajax` function in your view or script file. (Though *.blade.php is better place to execute this function as you'll be able to access the variables much easily.)

```js
// Javascript part
$.ajax({
    url: `{{ route() }}`,
    method: 'GET/POST/PUT/DELETE',
    data: {
        // If you want to send some params to the controller.
        // You will receive the contents in `$request` object.
    },

    done: result => {
        // This callback is only called when your request succeeds.
        // This is the place where you need to update your HTML via DOM manipulation.
    },
    
    fail: result => {
        // This callback is only called when your request fails.
    },

    always: () => {
        // This callback is always called after a specific request is completed.
    }
});
```

```php
<?php
class TestController extends Controller {
    public function calculate(Request $request) {
        // DO YOUR CALCULATION
        // Instead of returning view, return a JSON from here.
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'result' => 'YOUR_RESULT']);
    }
}
?>
```

jQuery API Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Laravel JSON Response Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses